# How do I remove the left hand of the piano in MuseScore and Finale?

Tags: musescore, finale

How do I remove the left hand of the piano in MuseScore and Finale? I want to listen to the separate score parts.

Comment: I suggest that you copy the piano piece onto a new document, so that you don't destroy the Left Hand part on the Original.

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer the MuseScore portion of the question:

1. With your score open, go to `Edit -> Instruments`.
2. On the right-hand side of the pop-up window, select the staff that you want to remove. (In this case, it most likely says "Bass clef" under the "Piano" heading.
3. Click `Remove` in the center column of this pop-up window.
4. Return to the score. The staff has been removed and thus will not be a part of your playback.

Answer (score 2):

In Finale, each staff is given its own audio channel.  From Studio View (`View -> Studio View`) you have solo and mute buttons for each staff, and there's also a mixer window (`Window -> Mixer`) that you can operate from any view.

Answer (score 1):

In MuseScore 3 when a part consists of more than one staves, it is possible to mute individual voices within each staff of the part by pressing buttons 1-4 of the corresponding row in the detail area of the mixer. So in the case of a piano part, pressing all four buttons of the upper (or lower) row will mute the right (or left) hand staff.